# Size of parameter array in funtion

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int size_f(vector<int> adj[])
{
    return sizeof(adj);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> adj[] = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};

    cout << sizeof(adj) << endl;

    cout << size_f(adj);
}
```

```
96
8
```

This is my program and its result. I don't understand why `size_f` return 8. Can you explain it for me? And how can I know size of array that is parameter of my funtion. Thank you.

Comment: `8` is returned because the size of pointers in your system is 8. Pass the size of array as another parameter to have functions know the size of array.

Comment: When declaring an argument using "array" syntax like you do, then the compiler will treat it as a pointer. In other words, as an argument the declaration `vector<int> adj[]` is exactly the same as `vector<int> *adj`. Perhaos you should use a vector of vectors? Or `std::array<std::arrays<int, 2>, 4>`?